# Convert string(with array format) into array - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm sending a string of data via CURL using data from post, and receiving a response in a string as well which is in the form on an array. I'm trying to convert such response into an actual Array. Heres the code I have so far:

the response string im getting is this:

> Test transaction_id="2401_02-29-12_22:28:34_0" action="payment"
>   result="success" to_from="to" amount="205.00" gross="205.00"
>   net="-0.85" custom="" business="XXXX@XXXX.com" item_name="XXXXX.XXX"
>   item_code="Product Name 3," quantity="1" transaction_type="authorized
>   payment" transaction_status="pending" transaction_date="2012-02-29
>   22:28:34" processing_rate="0.85" discount_fee="0.00"
>   first_name="TESTNAME" last_name="TESTLNAME" address="TESTADDRESS"
>   city="TESTCITY" state_or_province="AL" country="US"
>   zip_or_postal_code="12345" phone="1234562002" email="email@wemail.es"
>   shipment="yes" shipping_address="TESTADDRESS" shipping_city="TESTCITY"
>   shipping_state_or_province="AL" shipping_country="US"
>   shipping_zip_or_postal_code="12345" processing_time="0.2187"

And the code im using to get such response is

```
<?php

// Get variables from POST array into a string
$post_str = "action=payment&business="      .urlencode($this->input->post('business'))
    ."&vericode="                   .urlencode($this->input->post('vericode'))
    ."&item_name="                  .urlencode($this->input->post('item_name'))
    ."&item_code="                  .urlencode($this->input->post('item_code'))
    ."&quantity="                   .urlencode($this->input->post('quantity'))
    ."&amount="                     .urlencode($this->input->post('amount'))
    ."&cc_type="                    .urlencode($this->input->post('cc_type'))
    ."&cc_number="                  .urlencode($this->input->post('cc_number'))
    ."&cc_expdate="                 .urlencode($this->input->post('cc_expdate_year')).urlencode($this->input->post('cc_expdate_month'))
    ."&cc_security_code="           .urlencode($this->input->post('cc_security_code'))
    ."&shipment="                   .urlencode($this->input->post('shipment'))
    ."&first_name="                 .urlencode($this->input->post('first_name'))
    ."&last_name="                  .urlencode($this->input->post('last_name'))
    ."&address="                    .urlencode($this->input->post('address'))
    ."&city="                       .urlencode($this->input->post('city'))
    ."&state_or_province="          .urlencode($this->input->post('state_or_province'))
    ."&zip_or_postal_code="         .urlencode($this->input->post('zip_or_postal_code'))
    ."&country="                    .urlencode($this->input->post('country'))
    ."&shipping_address="           .urlencode($this->input->post('shipping_address'))
    ."&shipping_city="              .urlencode($this->input->post('shipping_city'))
    ."&shipping_state_or_province=" .urlencode($this->input->post('shipping_state_or_province'))
    ."&shipping_zip_or_postal_code=".urlencode($this->input->post('shipping_zip_or_postal_code'))
    ."&shipping_country="           .urlencode($this->input->post('shipping_country'))
    ."&phone="                      .urlencode($this->input->post('phone'))
    ."&email="                      .urlencode($this->input->post('email'))
    ."&ip_address="                 .urlencode($this->input->post('ip_address'))
    ."&website_unique_id="          .urlencode($this->input->post('website_unique_id'));

// Send URL string via CURL
$backendUrl = "https://www.veripayment.com/integration/index.php";
$this->curl->create($backendUrl);
$this->curl->post($post_str);

// get response from API
$return_str = $this->curl->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response you're receiving has elements separated by a space you might use

```
function parse($response)
{
    $result = array();
    $resparray = explode(' ', $response);
    if ($resparray)
    {
      foreach ($resparray as $resp) {
        $keyvalue = explode('=', $resp);
        $result[$keyvalue[0]] =  str_replace('"', '', $keyvalue[1]);
      }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Edited and corrected, Here's the output

```
Array ( [transaction_id] => 2401_02-29-12_22:28:34_0 [action] => payment [result] => success [to_from] => to [amount] => 205.00 [gross] => 205.00 [net] => -0.85 [custom] => [business] => XXXX@XXXX.com [item_name] => XXXXX.XXX [item_code] => Product [Name] => [3,"] => [quantity] => 1 [transaction_type] => authorized [payment"] => [transaction_status] => pending [transaction_date] => 2012-02-29 [22:28:34"] => [processing_rate] => 0.85 [discount_fee] => 0.00 [first_name] => TESTNAME [last_name] => TESTLNAME [address] => TESTADDRESS [city] => TESTCITY [state_or_province] => AL [country] => US [zip_or_postal_code] => 12345 [phone] => 1234562002 [email] => email@wemail.es [shipment] => yes [shipping_address] => TESTADDRESS [shipping_city] => TESTCITY [shipping_state_or_province] => AL [shipping_country] => US [shipping_zip_or_postal_code] => 12345 [processing_time] => 0.2187
```

Comment: Carlos I'm getting some errors on some of the indexes. It seems like its skiping some of the values:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: admin/test.php

Line Number: 65

the line is : $result[$keyvalue[0]] =  str_replace('"', '', $keyvalue[1]);

Comment: This method fails if any of the strings that were passed have spaces in them. For example, look at the part `transaction_type="authorized payment"`. Your code turned it into `[transaction_type] => authorized [payment"] => `.

It looks like making this approach work would require you to use regular expressions or something so you can split the string only at spaces that aren't inside quotes. I feel like there must be a better way...

Comment: I added an if statement inside the foreach, so it skips the errors, now im getting Array ( [transaction_id] => 2364_03-01-12_14:29:40_0 [action] => payment [result] => failed [errors] => 98 [errors_meaning] => (98) [customer_errors_meaning] => [processing_time] => 0.0372 ) 

which are the the main keys i needed. thanks